# Como encriptar y desencriptar datos en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

¿Cómo podría encriptar y desencriptar datos en una base de datos [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server)?

Tengo una tabla Usuarios, con diferentes campos y quiero encriptar el campo de contraseña.

<sub>Nota: En la siguiente respuesta estoy trabajando con una base de datos de Usuarios, con sus campos id, usuario, contraseñaEncriptada, etc...</sub>

Comment: Hace un mes aproximadamente busqué información en [SOes](http://www.es.stackoverflow.com) sobre encriptación de datos en SQL server y no encontré nada. Así que después de haber mirado en documentación en [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es) y en otros sitios, en la respuesta os dejomi desarrollo:

Comment: Cambié la etiqueta de Visual Basic 6 a VB.NET, porque el código en tu respuesta definitivamente no es VB6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Encriptar contraseña:**

```
Private Shared Function EncryptPassword(cadenaConexion As String, usuario As String,
    contraseña As String) As String

    Dim parUsuario As New SqlParameter("@usuario", usuario)
    Dim consulta As String = "DECLARE @FraseSuperSegura nvarchar(128);  
                            SET @FraseSuperSegura= N'Ejemplo de frase super segura';
                            UPDATE Usuarios SET
                            Contrasena_EncriptadaPorFraseSegura = EncriptarPorFraseSegura(
                            @FraseSuperSegura , Contrasena, 1, CONVERT(
                            varbinary, usuario)) WHERE usuario = @usuario;"
    Dim objDS As DataSet = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(cadenaConexion,
        CommandType.Text, consulta, parUsuario)
End Function
```

Contraseña Encriptada:

> *0x010000008D2ECCEE535FC014603EDE815ED641278E6D9CFEC20F929149A6B5EC05B8EEEC74C658D08B79D9148515952C76D37D78*

---

**Desencriptar contraseña:**

```
Private Shared Function DecryptPassword(CadenaConexion As String, Usuario As String, 
    Contraseña As String) As String
    Dim contraseñaDecrypted As String
    Dim parUsuario As New SqlParameter("@usuario", Usuario)
    Dim consulta As String = "DECLARE @FraseSuperSegura varchar(128);  
                            SET @FraseSuperSegura = N'Ejemplo de frase super segura';
                            SELECT usuario, Contrasena_EncriptadaPorFraseSegura, 
                            CONVERT(varchar, DesencriptarPorFraseSegura(@FraseSuperSegura ,
                            Contrasena_EncriptadaPorFraseSegura, 1, CONVERT(  
                            varbinary, usuario))) AS 'Contraseña' FROM Usuarios
                            WHERE usuario = @usuario"
    Dim objDS As DataSet = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(
                           CadenaConexion, CommandType.Text, consulta, parUsuario)

    'Compruebo si la contraseña desencriptada es la misma que la introducida por el usuario'  
    If (Contraseña.Equals(objDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2).ToString())) Then
        contraseñaDecrypted = objDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2).ToString()
    'Sino, al valor que devuelvo (contraseñaDecrypted) le pongo 1 para controlar el error'
    ElseIf (Usuario.Equals(objDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0).ToString())) Then
        contraseñaDecrypted = "1"
    End If
    Return contraseñaDecrypted

End Function
```

Usuario: *Test1234*

Contrasena_EncriptadaPorFraseSegura:

> *0x010000008D2ECCEE535FC014603EDE815ED641278E6D9CFEC20F929149A6B5EC05B8EEEC74C658D08B79D9148515952C76D37D78*

Contraseña: *Test1234+*

Comment: Gracias por compartir, pero para que tu respuesta realmente sea util para alguien mas, tendrías que compartir los detalles de las funciones `EncriptarPorFraseSegura` y `DesencriptarPorFraseSegura`. Y aunque es una decisión personal, pero, cuando se trata de contraseñas, es preferible usar un "one way hash", o sea que no se pueda desencriptar. Si no, que es la comparación de los hash que determina si el usuario puso la contraseña correcta. Encriptar y desencriptar es mas apropiado para cosas como numeros de carta de credito, etc.